# Failed to compile pandoc with cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, pandoc

I try to install pandoc today on my Ubuntu12.04 system with:

```
cabal install pandoc-1.11.1 -v3
```

I choose this version becasue I am using it on my another ubuntu12.04 system, but it failed when compiling Reader.Markdown. 
I am not sure what to do, any help?

Error showed as :

```
searching for ghc in path.
found ghc at /usr/bin/ghc
("/usr/bin/ghc",["--numeric-version"])
/usr/bin/ghc is version 7.4.1
looking for tool "ghc-pkg" near compiler in /usr/bin
found ghc-pkg in /usr/bin/ghc-pkg
("/usr/bin/ghc-pkg",["--version"])
/usr/bin/ghc-pkg is version 7.4.1
("/usr/bin/ghc",["--supported-languages"])
("/usr/bin/ghc",["--info"])
Reading installed packages...
("/usr/bin/ghc-pkg",["dump","--global","-v0"])
("/usr/bin/ghc-pkg",["dump","--user","-v0"])
("/usr/bin/ghc",["--print-libdir"])
Reading available packages...
Choosing modular solver.
Resolving dependencies...
[__0] trying: blogmd-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] trying: base-4.5.0.0/installed-c8e... (dependency of blogmd-0.1.0.0)
[__2] trying: rts-1.0/installedbuil... (dependency of base-4.5.0.0/installed-c8e...)
[__3] trying: integer-gmp-0.4.0.0/installed-ec8... (dependency of base-4.5.0.0/installed-c8e...)
[__4] trying: ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/installed-bd2... (dependency of base-4.5.0.0/installed-c8e...)
[__5] next goal: pandoc (dependency of blogmd-0.1.0.0)
[__5] rejecting: pandoc-1.12.0.2, 1.12.0.1, 1.12 (conflict: blogmd => pandoc==1.11.1)
[__5] trying: pandoc-1.11.1
[__6] trying: pandoc-1.11.1:-embed_data_files
[__7] trying: pandoc-1.11.1:+blaze_html_0_5
[__8] trying: pandoc-1.11.1:!bench
[__9] trying: pandoc-1.11.1:!test
```

...

```
Flags chosen: embed_data_files=False, blaze_html_0_5=True
Dependency HTTP ==4000.2.8: using HTTP-4000.2.8
Dependency base ==4.5.0.0: using base-4.5.0.0
Dependency base64-bytestring ==1.0.0.1: using base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1
Dependency blaze-html ==0.6.1.1: using blaze-html-0.6.1.1
Dependency blaze-markup ==0.5.1.5: using blaze-markup-0.5.1.5
Dependency bytestring ==0.9.2.1: using bytestring-0.9.2.1
Dependency citeproc-hs ==0.3.8: using citeproc-hs-0.3.8
Dependency containers ==0.4.2.1: using containers-0.4.2.1
Dependency data-default ==0.5.3: using data-default-0.5.3
Dependency directory ==1.1.0.2: using directory-1.1.0.2
Dependency extensible-exceptions ==0.1.1.4: using
extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.4
Dependency filepath ==1.3.0.0: using filepath-1.3.0.0
Dependency highlighting-kate ==0.5.5: using highlighting-kate-0.5.5
Dependency json ==0.7: using json-0.7
Dependency mtl ==2.1.2: using mtl-2.1.2
Dependency network ==2.4.1.2: using network-2.4.1.2
Dependency old-locale ==1.0.0.4: using old-locale-1.0.0.4
Dependency old-time ==1.1.0.0: using old-time-1.1.0.0
Dependency pandoc -any: using pandoc-1.11.1
Dependency pandoc-types ==1.10: using pandoc-types-1.10
Dependency parsec ==3.1.3: using parsec-3.1.3
Dependency process ==1.1.0.1: using process-1.1.0.1
Dependency random ==1.0.1.1: using random-1.0.1.1
Dependency syb ==0.3.6: using syb-0.3.6
Dependency tagsoup ==0.12.8: using tagsoup-0.12.8
Dependency temporary ==1.1.2.4: using temporary-1.1.2.4
Dependency texmath ==0.6.4: using texmath-0.6.4
Dependency text ==0.11.1.13: using text-0.11.1.13
Dependency time ==1.4: using time-1.4
Dependency xml ==1.3.13: using xml-1.3.13
Dependency zip-archive ==0.1.3.4: using zip-archive-0.1.3.4
Dependency zlib ==0.5.3.3: using zlib-0.5.3.3
searching for alex in path.
found alex at /usr/bin/alex
("/usr/bin/alex",["--version"])
/usr/bin/alex is version 3.0.1
searching for ar in path.
found ar at /usr/bin/ar
searching for c2hs in path.
Cannot find c2hs on the path
searching for cpphs in path.
Cannot find cpphs on the path
searching for ffihugs in path.
Cannot find ffihugs on the path
searching for gcc in path.
found gcc at /usr/bin/gcc
("/usr/bin/gcc",["-dumpversion"])
/usr/bin/gcc is version 4.6
searching for greencard in path.
Cannot find greencard on the path
searching for haddock in path.
found haddock at /usr/bin/haddock
("/usr/bin/haddock",["--version"])
/usr/bin/haddock is version 2.10.0
searching for happy in path.
found happy at /usr/bin/happy
("/usr/bin/happy",["--version"])
/usr/bin/happy is version 1.18.9
searching for hmake in path.
Cannot find hmake on the path
searching for hpc in path.
found hpc at /usr/bin/hpc
("/usr/bin/hpc",["version"])
/usr/bin/hpc is version 0.6
looking for tool "hsc2hs" near compiler in /usr/bin
found hsc2hs in /usr/bin/hsc2hs
("/usr/bin/hsc2hs",["--version"])
/usr/bin/hsc2hs is version 0.67
searching for HsColour in path.
Cannot find HsColour on the path
searching for hugs in path.
Cannot find hugs on the path
searching for jhc in path.
Cannot find jhc on the path
searching for ld in path.
found ld at /usr/bin/ld
("/usr/bin/ghc",["-c","/tmp/29426.c","-o","/tmp/29426.o"])
("/usr/bin/ld",["-x","-r","/tmp/29426.o","-o","/tmp/29427.o"])
searching for lhc in path.
Cannot find lhc on the path
searching for lhc-pkg in path.
Cannot find lhc-pkg on the path
searching for nhc98 in path.
Cannot find nhc98 on the path
searching for pkg-config in path.
Cannot find pkg-config on the path
searching for ranlib in path.
found ranlib at /usr/bin/ranlib
searching for strip in path.
found strip at /usr/bin/strip
searching for tar in path.
found tar at /bin/tar
searching for uhc in path.
Cannot find uhc on the path
Using Cabal-1.14.0 compiled by ghc-7.4
Using compiler: ghc-7.4.1
Using install prefix: /home/lyntonzhang/.cabal
Binaries installed in: /home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/bin
Libraries installed in: /home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/pandoc-1.11.1/ghc-7.4.1
Private binaries installed in: /home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/libexec
Data files installed in: /home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/share/pandoc-1.11.1
Documentation installed in: /home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/share/doc/pandoc-1.11.1
Using alex version 3.0.1 found on system at: /usr/bin/alex
Using ar found on system at: /usr/bin/ar
No c2hs found
No cpphs found
No ffihugs found
Using gcc version 4.6 found on system at: /usr/bin/gcc
Using ghc version 7.4.1 found on system at: /usr/bin/ghc
Using ghc-pkg version 7.4.1 found on system at: /usr/bin/ghc-pkg
No greencard found
Using haddock version 2.10.0 found on system at: /usr/bin/haddock
Using happy version 1.18.9 found on system at: /usr/bin/happy
No hmake found
Using hpc version 0.6 found on system at: /usr/bin/hpc
Using hsc2hs version 0.67 found on system at: /usr/bin/hsc2hs
No hscolour found
No hugs found
No jhc found
Using ld found on system at: /usr/bin/ld
No lhc found
No lhc-pkg found
No nhc98 found
No pkg-config found
Using ranlib found on system at: /usr/bin/ranlib
Using strip found on system at: /usr/bin/strip
Using tar found on system at: /bin/tar
No uhc found
("/usr/bin/gcc",["-Wl,--hash-size=31","-Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads","/tmp/29426.c","-o","/tmp/29426","-D__GLASGOW_HASKELL__=704","-Idist/build/autogen","-I.","-I/usr/lib/ghc/process-1.1.0.1/include","-I/usr/lib/ghc/time-1.4/include","-I/usr/lib/ghc/directory-1.1.0.2/include","-I/usr/lib/ghc/old-time-1.1.0.0/include","-I/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/network-2.4.1.2/ghc-7.4.1/include","-I/usr/lib/ghc/unix-2.5.1.0/include","-I/usr/lib/ghc/bytestring-0.9.2.1/include","-I/usr/lib/ghc/base-4.5.0.0/include","-I/usr/lib/ghc/include","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/zip-archive-0.1.3.4/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/haskell-packages/ghc/lib/zlib-0.5.3.3/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/texmath-0.6.4/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/xml-1.3.13/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/temporary-1.1.2.4/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/tagsoup-0.12.8/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/haskell-packages/ghc/lib/random-1.0.1.1/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/ghc/process-1.1.0.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/highlighting-kate-0.5.5/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.7.8.31/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/haskell-packages/ghc/lib/regex-base-0.93.2/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/haskell-packages/ghc/lib/mtl-2.0.1.0/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/haskell-packages/ghc/lib/transformers-0.2.2.0/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/digest-0.0.1.2/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/data-default-0.5.3/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/data-default-instances-old-locale-0.0.1/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/data-default-instances-dlist-0.0.1/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/dlist-0.5/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/data-default-instances-containers-0.0.1/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/data-default-instances-base-0.0.1/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/data-default-class-0.0.1/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/citeproc-hs-0.3.8/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/ghc/time-1.4","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/pandoc-types-1.10/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/json-0.7/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/ghc/pretty-1.1.1.0","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/hs-bibutils-5.0/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/haskell-packages/ghc/lib/syb-0.3.6/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/hexpat-0.20.3/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/utf8-string-0.3.7/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/ghc/extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.4","-L/usr/lib/ghc/directory-1.1.0.2","-L/usr/lib/ghc/filepath-1.3.0.0","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/blaze-html-0.6.1.1/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/blaze-markup-0.5.1.5/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/blaze-builder-0.3.1.1/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/ghc/binary-0.5.1.0","-L/usr/lib/ghc/containers-0.4.2.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/List-0.5.1/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/HTTP-4000.2.8/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/ghc/old-time-1.1.0.0","-L/usr/lib/ghc/old-locale-1.0.0.4","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/network-2.4.1.2/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/ghc/unix-2.5.1.0","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/parsec-3.1.3/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/haskell-packages/ghc/lib/text-0.11.1.13/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/ghc/deepseq-1.3.0.0","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/mtl-2.1.2/ghc-7.4.1","-L/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal/lib/transformers-0.3.0.0/ghc-7.4.1","-L/usr/lib/ghc/bytestring-0.9.2.1","-L/usr/lib/ghc/array-0.4.0.0","-L/usr/lib/ghc/base-4.5.0.0","-L/usr/lib/ghc/integer-gmp-0.4.0.0","-L/usr/lib/ghc/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0","-L/usr/lib/ghc"])
/tmp/pandoc-1.11.1-29370/pandoc-1.11.1/dist/setup/setup configure --verbose=3
--ghc --prefix=/home/lyntonzhang/.cabal --user --flags=-embed_data_files
--flags=blaze_html_0_5 --constraint=zlib ==0.5.3.3 --constraint=zip-archive
==0.1.3.4 --constraint=xml ==1.3.13 --constraint=time ==1.4 --constraint=text
==0.11.1.13 --constraint=texmath ==0.6.4 --constraint=temporary ==1.1.2.4
--constraint=tagsoup ==0.12.8 --constraint=syb ==0.3.6 --constraint=random
==1.0.1.1 --constraint=process ==1.1.0.1 --constraint=parsec ==3.1.3
--constraint=pandoc-types ==1.10 --constraint=old-time ==1.1.0.0
--constraint=old-locale ==1.0.0.4 --constraint=network ==2.4.1.2
--constraint=mtl ==2.1.2 --constraint=json ==0.7
--constraint=highlighting-kate ==0.5.5 --constraint=filepath ==1.3.0.0
--constraint=extensible-exceptions ==0.1.1.4 --constraint=directory ==1.1.0.2
--constraint=data-default ==0.5.3 --constraint=containers ==0.4.2.1
--constraint=citeproc-hs ==0.3.8 --constraint=bytestring ==0.9.2.1
--constraint=blaze-markup ==0.5.1.5 --constraint=blaze-html ==0.6.1.1
--constraint=base64-bytestring ==1.0.0.1 --constraint=base ==4.5.0.0
--constraint=HTTP ==4000.2.8 --disable-tests --disable-benchmarks
Using external setup method with build-type Custom
creating /tmp/pandoc-1.11.1-29370/pandoc-1.11.1/dist/setup
Using Cabal library version 1.14.0
Using /tmp/pandoc-1.11.1-29370/pandoc-1.11.1/Setup.hs as setup script.
creating dist/build
creating dist/build/autogen
Building pandoc-1.11.1...
Preprocessing library pandoc-1.11.1...
Building library...
creating dist/build
("/usr/bin/ghc",["--make","-package-name","pandoc-1.11.1","-v","-hide-all-packages","-fbuilding-cabal-package","-i","-idist/build","-isrc","-idist/build/autogen","-Idist/build/autogen","-Idist/build","-optP-include","-optPdist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h","-odir","dist/build","-hidir","dist/build","-stubdir","dist/build","-package-id","HTTP-4000.2.8-38cfa9eb001dc096a2322525b343c875","-package-id","base-4.5.0.0-c8e7184681d410015e93df85fc49e9dd","-package-id","base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1-8861681d98d07ca1bd6021178e397139","-package-id","blaze-html-0.6.1.1-b629ace7677c9a90a3bf924727d6bbed","-package-id","blaze-markup-0.5.1.5-3ad15c648fab31c4e1ffe2f14dc5c629","-package-id","bytestring-0.9.2.1-4adca9710b1386944aaca5a7886ef98f","-package-id","citeproc-hs-0.3.8-37c83a865f08f5ec9126429e31ec7299","-package-id","containers-0.4.2.1-7c54595400348f577b3b4a45691c5afd","-package-id","data-default-0.5.3-efcd7c653eab26600a3f1f9dc1080e52","-package-id","directory-1.1.0.2-8957520ced1fb19160c3a6126dcccfaa","-package-id","extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.4-d27a1ac47e54880cae007cceceb41580","-package-id","filepath-1.3.0.0-674b8a582fb49f1c9724f50a6a5d5768","-package-id","highlighting-kate-0.5.5-b8aee7ed0991e011cb83ef818570be4e","-package-id","json-0.7-32ddb5e9e515360a309252068a497d00","-package-id","mtl-2.1.2-b4218b10f76494af94aa7e4a289ef6ff","-package-id","network-2.4.1.2-805eb55e9816f3d10322388767a4e316","-package-id","old-locale-1.0.0.4-29bd50ed2bb4a20928338f52e4ab1b71","-package-id","pandoc-types-1.10-2f1764bf1d59410ed40c1353f14caed1","-package-id","parsec-3.1.3-70ca601dfa4f285ef1ec63e38198250a","-package-id","process-1.1.0.1-91185c964ab744c1f3cbca1863d2ba45","-package-id","random-1.0.1.1-3bece392c9f5221263ed25c90c28e1ec","-package-id","syb-0.3.6-05925f4440bc3fbb54d5c12bac109e49","-package-id","tagsoup-0.12.8-d9dc16b0a5a834b5df04b4fc78c12c15","-package-id","temporary-1.1.2.4-14218d4c08a1601337ed533381e31b38","-package-id","texmath-0.6.4-2f4fcb0613992149f461413e42c18e76","-package-id","text-0.11.1.13-501afa4d95a2591bf1e0d0a57dc80a38","-package-id","time-1.4-3e186a51d3674e5d65b5a7925db3d3a7","-package-id","xml-1.3.13-8516278fb40b2a2f8c9ebd720024d3a8","-package-id","zip-archive-0.1.3.4-7cea4a0add4d54438ee3e9e6e183a035","-package-id","zlib-0.5.3.3-9ed15628a121b3b57f97b7acc02bf5d9","-O","-rtsopts","-Wall","-fno-warn-unused-do-bind","-XHaskell98","-XCPP","Text.Pandoc","Text.Pandoc.Options","Text.Pandoc.Pretty","Text.Pandoc.Shared","Text.Pandoc.Readers.HTML","Text.Pandoc.Readers.LaTeX","Text.Pandoc.Readers.Markdown","Text.Pandoc.Readers.MediaWiki","Text.Pandoc.Readers.RST","Text.Pandoc.Readers.DocBook","Text.Pandoc.Readers.TeXMath","Text.Pandoc.Readers.Textile","Text.Pandoc.Readers.Native","Text.Pandoc.Writers.Native","Text.Pandoc.Writers.Docbook","Text.Pandoc.Writers.HTML","Text.Pandoc.Writers.LaTeX","Text.Pandoc.Writers.ConTeXt","Text.Pandoc.Writers.OpenDocument","Text.Pandoc.Writers.Texinfo","Text.Pandoc.Writers.Man","Text.Pandoc.Writers.Markdown","Text.Pandoc.Writers.RST","Text.Pandoc.Writers.Org","Text.Pandoc.Writers.AsciiDoc","Text.Pandoc.Writers.Textile","Text.Pandoc.Writers.MediaWiki","Text.Pandoc.Writers.RTF","Text.Pandoc.Writers.ODT","Text.Pandoc.Writers.Docx","Text.Pandoc.Writers.EPUB","Text.Pandoc.Writers.FB2","Text.Pandoc.PDF","Text.Pandoc.UTF8","Text.Pandoc.Templates","Text.Pandoc.XML","Text.Pandoc.Biblio","Text.Pandoc.SelfContained","Text.Pandoc.MIME","Text.Pandoc.Parsing","Text.Pandoc.UUID","Text.Pandoc.ImageSize","Text.Pandoc.Slides","Text.Pandoc.Highlighting","Paths_pandoc"])
[ 1 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Pretty ( src/Text/Pandoc/Pretty.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Pretty.o )
[ 2 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Readers.TeXMath ( src/Text/Pandoc/Readers/TeXMath.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Readers/TeXMath.o )
[ 3 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.UTF8 ( src/Text/Pandoc/UTF8.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/UTF8.o )
[ 4 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.PDF  ( src/Text/Pandoc/PDF.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/PDF.o )
[ 5 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.XML  ( src/Text/Pandoc/XML.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/XML.o )
[ 6 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.MIME ( src/Text/Pandoc/MIME.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/MIME.o )
[ 7 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.UUID ( src/Text/Pandoc/UUID.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/UUID.o )
[ 8 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.ImageSize ( src/Text/Pandoc/ImageSize.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/ImageSize.o )
[ 9 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Slides ( src/Text/Pandoc/Slides.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Slides.o )
[10 of 45] Compiling Paths_pandoc     ( dist/build/autogen/Paths_pandoc.hs, dist/build/Paths_pandoc.o )
[11 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Shared ( src/Text/Pandoc/Shared.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Shared.o )
[12 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Highlighting ( src/Text/Pandoc/Highlighting.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Highlighting.o )
[13 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Options ( src/Text/Pandoc/Options.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Options.o )
[14 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.Native ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Native.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Native.o )
[15 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Readers.DocBook ( src/Text/Pandoc/Readers/DocBook.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Readers/DocBook.o )
[16 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Parsing ( src/Text/Pandoc/Parsing.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Parsing.o )
[17 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.SelfContained ( src/Text/Pandoc/SelfContained.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/SelfContained.o )
[18 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Biblio ( src/Text/Pandoc/Biblio.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Biblio.o )
[19 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Templates ( src/Text/Pandoc/Templates.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Templates.o )
[20 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.OpenDocument ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/OpenDocument.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/OpenDocument.o )
[21 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.FB2 ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/FB2.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/FB2.o )
[22 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.Docx ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Docx.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Docx.o )
[23 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.ODT ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/ODT.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/ODT.o )
[24 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.RTF ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/RTF.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/RTF.o )
[25 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.MediaWiki ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/MediaWiki.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/MediaWiki.o )
[26 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.Textile ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Textile.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Textile.o )
[27 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.AsciiDoc ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/AsciiDoc.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/AsciiDoc.o )
[28 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.Org ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Org.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Org.o )
[29 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.RST ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/RST.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/RST.o )
[30 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.Man ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Man.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Man.o )
[31 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.Texinfo ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Texinfo.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Texinfo.o )
[32 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.ConTeXt ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/ConTeXt.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/ConTeXt.o )
[33 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.LaTeX ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/LaTeX.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/LaTeX.o )
[34 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.HTML ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/HTML.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/HTML.o )
[35 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.Markdown ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Markdown.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Markdown.o )
[36 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.EPUB ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/EPUB.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/EPUB.o )
[37 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.Docbook ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Docbook.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Docbook.o )
[38 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Readers.Native ( src/Text/Pandoc/Readers/Native.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Readers/Native.o )
[39 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Readers.RST ( src/Text/Pandoc/Readers/RST.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Readers/RST.o )
[40 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Readers.LaTeX ( src/Text/Pandoc/Readers/LaTeX.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Readers/LaTeX.o )
/usr/bin/ghc returned ExitFailure 9
```

I just clean my .cabal and .ghc file and try to run :

```
cabal install pandoc
```

and the error is :

```
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
http-conduit-1.9.5.1 depends on socks-0.5.1 which failed to install.
mime-types-0.1.0.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 9
pandoc-1.12.0.2 depends on socks-0.5.1 which failed to install.
socks-0.5.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Is there any way to install pandoc on a new machine?

and then I clean the .ghc and .cabal file again ,and run :

```
cabal install snap-1.11.1
```

and this time the error is :

```
[35 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Parsing ( src/Text/Pandoc/Parsing.hs,        dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Parsing.o )
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
pandoc-1.11.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 9
```

I have spend a whole day try to make it work, now I think I jsut have to give up.

---

My memory is :

```
~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1000        958         42          0         25        228
-/+ buffers/cache:        705        295
Swap:          255        255          0
```

I still have 295M, so I don't think it is because of not enough memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How much RAM do you have on the machine?  It looks like the error one gets when the compiler runs out of memory.

Comment: `~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1000        958         42          0         25        228
-/+ buffers/cache:        705        295
Swap:          255        255          0`

Comment: @user2663919, you can check whether the OOM killer was triggered recently (as I suspect) with `dmesg`.

Comment: `mppe_compress[0]: osize too small! (have: 1404 need: 1408)
ppp0: ppp: compressor dropped pkt` Is this want you mean OOM?

Comment: There should be a big section of the dmesg output that looks like the one in this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/56874/oom-killer-killing-processes-despite-having-plenty-of-free-swap

Comment: No, I don't have anything like that on dmesg output, I just have the above message showing again and again.

Comment: Oh, well then probably the OOM message was too long ago and the dmesg buffer has been filled up by those unrelated messages.

Answer (score 2):

With 1G of ram it's possible you are running out of memory, as John says, depending on what other large processes are running. Another way to check this is to watch memory usage with top or htop during the install. In top you can type `m` to show large processes at the top, and `s 0.1` to make it update quicker.

You can influence cabal to use less memory by adding eg `+RTS -M200m` to the cabal install command. It's not exact, and you shouldn't use either too much or too little, so you may need to adjust that number up or down. If your cabal rejects that option, which it probably will, then first reinstall it with the rtsopts option:

```
cabal install cabal-install --ghc-options=-rtsopts
```

Or, temporarily kill off some other large processes until the install completes.

Or, try doing the cabal install in stages, installing major dependencies first and finally the desired package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am not the manager of the system so I cannot kick off other process..after `cabal install cabal-install --ghc-options=-rtsopts` I still cannot use `+RTS -M200m1 options and cabal complains that most rtsopts are disabled.

Comment: Check you are running the just-installed cabal. `which -a cabal` might show several in your PATH. Also I assume your `1` there was a typo.

Comment: Indeed, I installed the new cabal on my .cabal/bin, but even with the `+RTS -M200m` I still cannot compile it (tried 200-500m) , I think I have to figure another way out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my raspberry pi 3 while I was trying to make Idris programming language using cabal.
I got ExitFailure (-9) with this description:
This may be due to an out-of-memory condition.
I fixed the problem by increasing my swap space. first I edit the `/etc/dphys-swapfile` (change the `CONF_SWAPSIZE=100`) and change the size to 512 MB.
then:

```
/etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile stop
/etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile start
```